# Detect a partial match in a column in a df1 with a column in df2 and output the matched value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, string-matching

I have two dataframes in R:

```
col1 <- c("Apple pie", "Orange soda", "Pear", "Strawberry milkshake", "Kiwi")

col2 <- c("Delicious", "Refreshing", "Crunchy", "Creamy", "Sweet")

df1 <- data.frame(col1, col2)

fruits <- c("Blueberry", "Apple", "Pear", "Orange", "Watermelon", "Honeydew", "Dragonfruit", "Strawberry")

df2 <- as.data.frame(fruits)
```

I want to see if there are any values in df1 that matches with those in df2 For example, I would want "Apple pie" to match with "Apple" and "Orange soda" to match with "Orange".

I want to end up with a df1 that looks like the following:

```
col3 <- c("Apple", "Orange", "Pear", NA, NA)
  
df1 <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3)
```

I assume the code would be structured something like the following:

```
df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(
    col3 = ifelse(df2$fruits %in% str_detect(col1),
                  df2$fruits, NA)
  )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `map` function:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
    mutate(col3 = map(col1, ~df2$fruits[str_detect(.x, df2$fruits)]))
```

This covers the basic elements, but you'd need to do some work to clean up the output, as it is a list column.

Another option would be to use `fuzzy_left_join` from **`fuzzy_join`** package:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fuzzyjoin)

df1 %>%
    fuzzy_left_join(df2, by = c("col1" = "fruits"),
                    match_fun = str_detect)

                  col1       col2     fruits
1            Apple pie  Delicious      Apple
2          Orange soda Refreshing     Orange
3                 Pear    Crunchy       Pear
4 Strawberry milkshake     Creamy Strawberry
5                 Kiwi      Sweet       <NA>
```